# Codeigniter only routing to default

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, routes, default

I'm currently learning to use Codeigniter, I'm able to route successfully to the default controller's index method, but when trying to route to another page (e.g. localhost/results), I'm only taken back to the default page but the URL is changed to the new controller or method (e.g. from localhost to localhost/results displays the same page as just localhost).

config.php settings:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['result'] = 'result';
```

.htaccess page:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

controller home.php:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {


  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('home_view');

  }
}
```

controller result.php:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Result extends CI_Controller {


  public function index()
  {
    var_dump($this->input->post());
  }

}
```

view home_view.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="result" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try adding the method like: $route['result'] = 'result/index';

Comment: Just tried changing it in the routes.php file. no luck. thank you though

Comment: Are you using WAMP or Xampp?

Comment: Was using WAMP, but had some problems with it. It was then suggested to me to use MAMP even though I'm on PC. So I'm still on MAMP.

Comment: Everything I try gets routed to the default page (e.g. localhost/nothome , localhost/home/fakemethod , etc...). If I set the default controller to the result controller then it displays correctly. So I believe its a problem with either the routing or the htaccess file since while the default is set to the home controller, and I navigate to localhost/result it takes me back to the index page.

Comment: When you use the new version couple checks you need to do is make sure the file names and class names have first letter as upper case. It may work when on lower case on local host but when go to a live server may cause problem.

Comment: Yeah, I think I was using CI 2.0 conventions and it was causing problems with the newer version. I just reverted to the older version to learn the basics and then I can update in the future. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I wound up just reverting to the older version of Codeigniter. It appears to be working now with the same set up as before. Thank everyone for the responses and help.

Answer (score 0):

This may only be a partial answer, but...

Two things to do.

1. Definitely set a value for `$config['base_url']`
2. Set `$config['index_page'] =  ''` This is important when using mod-rewrite as you are.

And

3. (I know I said two things. But thought of another.)

You may get better results using an absolute URL in the action attribute of your form like so.

```
<form action= <?php echo base_url("result"); ?> method="post">
```

base_url() relies on `$config['base_url']` being set. You'll need to do the followingsomewhere earlier in the controller too.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

4. (I know, but I keep seeing other stuff)... 4. Remove `$route['result'] = 'result';` from routes.php.

If these don't help I would suggest you comment out the .htaccess lines related to protecting the system and application folders just to be certain that's not an issue.

Comment: Worked my way down the list. Still no luck. I've even tried removing my htaccess file and just going with the index.php in the url but that didn't fix the problem either. Thank you for your help though.